# Paperclip and Amazon S3 Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a rails app running on Heroku. I am using paperclip for some simple image uploads for user avatars and some other things, I have S3 set as my backend and everything seems to be working fine except when trying to push to S3 I get the following error:

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Thinking I mis-pasted my access key and secret key, I tried again, still no luck. Thinking maybe it was just a buggy key I deactivated it and generated a new one. Still no luck.

Now for both keys I have used the S3 browser app on OS X and have been able to connect to each and view my current buckets and add/delete buckets. Is there something I should be looking out for? I have my application's S3 and paperclip setup like so

```
development:
  bucket: (unique name)
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY']
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']

test:
  bucket: (unique name)
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY']
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']

production:
  bucket: (unique_name)
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY']
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']

has_attached_file :cover,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => "50x50"
    },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => ":class/:id/:style/:filename"
```

EDIT NOTE: The ENV['S3_KEY'] and ENV['S3_SECRET'] are environment variables in heroku which i have tried even using my keys directly and it still doesn't work

Note: I just added the (unique name) bits, those aren't actually there--I have also verified bucket names, but I don't even think this is getting that far. I also have my heroku environment vars setup correctly and have them setup on dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't setting a bucket. It's in your s3.yml file, but you aren't reading that value from your call to `has_attached_file`.

Paperclip S3 docs:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3#s3_protocol-instance_method

Also, pay attention to those people who are telling you not to use a s3.yml file with Heroku. It's a waste and just added abstraction that buys you nothing. You already have your ENV set up with the values you need, so use them.

I've done this before where I don't want to push an s3.yml file to Heroku, but I do want to use one for test and development. In an initializer you can do something like this:

```
# If an s3.yml file exists, use the key, secret key, and bucket values from there.
# Otherwise, pull them from the environment.
if File.exists?("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")
  s3_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")
  S3[:key] = s3_config[Rails.env]['key']
  S3[:secret] = s3_config[Rails.env]['secret']
  S3[:bucket] = s3_config[Rails.env]['bucket']
else
  S3[:key] = ENV['S3_KEY']
  S3[:secret] = ENV['S3_SECRET']
  S3[:bucket] = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
```

Then when you're setting up Paperclip in your model, you reference the value like this:

```
...
:s3_credentials => {
  :access_key_id => S3[:key],
  :secret_access_key => S3[:secret]
},
:bucket => S3[:bucket]
```

Obviously, this means that you do not want to have your s3.yml file in your git repository (which really, you shouldn't anyway).

Comment: While this is true, check the error in the original post. It indicates the access_key_id isn't even being accepted so buckets would not yet be in play.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, but inlining my access keys (even though they're environment variables) worked... I don't know why, I was following Heroku's advice to the T but this ended up working, thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add the s3.yml to your git ignore list so it won't show up on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, and you should. In my example of using an s3.yml file for dev and test, that's exactly what I do. You still, however, need to supply these values somehow to Heroku.

Comment: Actually if you specify a config file, it should read in the bucket settings you've defined there.  That's how I've got my system set up and it's working fine.

Comment: This was answered a year and a half ago, so the gems could have changed since then. If you have more updated info, please edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I kept getting the same `AWS::S3::InvalidAccessKeyId` error, and had a very similar s3.yml file. As x1a4 recommended, I used ERB in my yaml file and it worked. Here's what it looks like now:

```
# myapp/config/s3.yml

development: &DEFAULTS
  bucket: myapp_dev
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>

test:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
  bucket: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
  bucket: myapp

staging:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
  bucket: myapp_staging
```

I guess this might a tad too indirect for some folks, but it seemed like the cleanest implementation to me.

Comment: You are my complete hero!

Answer (score 1):

Your s3 yaml file is actually using the strings `ENV['S3_KEY']` and `ENV['S3_SECRET']` as the auth info for s3. They are not being evaluated as ruby code.

There are a couple of things at least that you can do outside of putting that actual info into the yaml file. You can [look into enabling ERB in your yaml configs](http://urgetopunt.com/rails/2009/09/12/yaml-config-with-erb.html) or just not use a yaml file for your credentials at all, because you're always pulling from the environment in every one of your rails_envs, so the yaml file is just an extra layer of indirection in your case that is useless.

Comment: +1 Here's another helpful link from Heroku's blog - http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/4/7/config-vars/

Comment: thats's exactly what i'm doing

Comment: @Jimmy It's not what you're doing. You're putting the ENV stuff in the yaml file, where *it will not be treated as Ruby code*. The examples in the Heroku blog post put the ENV evaluation into the class itself, which is also fine, of course, and removes the need for declaring it for each environment separately in the s3.yml file.

Comment: Read my update--even putting the keys in directly still doesn't work

Comment: There's something else that we can't see, then. If the correct s3 auth info is in s3.yml then there's something else happening. Need to see more code, I guess. The code showing in the original question as it is right now will definitely not work.

Comment: Yeah I really don't understand it, even when putting in my s3 keys directly I am not able to connect, I've tried multiple times with multiple keys and still nothing, not even a response in the s3 forums

Comment: Are you able to get help from Heroku directly? That's likely your best bet at this point.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with Heroku as I can't even upload when running locally and get the Access key doesn't exist error then as well (Note I am replacing the ENV variables with the real keys when running locally)