# AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey in Paperclip but I've defined both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm on Heroku, and this is a portfolio thing which I'm putting up on github for potential employers to look at, so obviously I don't want to stick my keys in a S3.yml file. I've exported S3_KEY and S3_SECRET to my environment both on Heroku and my machine and ruby can access them. But when I try and upload, it gives me the following error:

```
AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey in Portfolio itemsController#update

You did not provide both required access keys. Please provide the access_key_id and the secret_access_key.
```

The trace is irrelevant except for my controller line #, which works fine until I try and upload a file. Here's what I have:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :portfolio_item_id, :order

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => "100x100#",
      :small => "300x300",
      :large => "600x600>"
               },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV["S3_KEY"],
      :secret_access_key => ENV["S3_SECRET"]
                       },
    :bucket => "bucketybucket",
    :path => "portfolio"

end
```

Anyone know what's going on here? How am I constructing this hash wrong?

Oh, and I've followed this thread, no dice: [Paperclip and Amazon S3 Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019411/paperclip-and-amazon-s3-issue)

Comment: having this exact same issue... were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

same problem...

seems like that ENV const doesn't load before loading the module. solve by using file argument
 like this

```
:s3_credentials => Rails.root.join('config/amazon_s3.yml')
```

and in amazon_s3.yml

```
access_key_id: 'your_key'
secret_access_key: 'your_sec_key'
bucket: 'somebucket'
```

furthermore, you can set environment variable by using **heroku config:add** command, which is describe in [Heroku DevCenter](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the Enviroment variable in heroku is different that the enviroment variable in your system, so it may happen that the application works just in one enviroment